# How do I make "-c" command permanent?

Tags: windbg

I want to run a initial command every time windbg starts, then I had to use `windbg -c blabla`  all the time.

Is there a configuration file / registry key to write to? So that windbg runs them automatically on start, either as a debugger or started manually by the user

Comment: Could you not just create a shortcut/batch file and pass these arguements in the shortcut/batch file? I don't think windbg has any reg settings that would achieve what you want. You can use a [commandtree file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/09/17/special-command-execute-commands-from-a-customized-user-interface-with-cmdtree.aspx) but this would still require you clicking on the command to load the script once you started WinDbg which I'm not sure saves you much in this instance

Comment: Hi @EdChum When windbg works as the default debugger for crashed programs, would this still work?

Comment: yes it should, it writes into regkey `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug 'Debugger'` the string `"C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe" -p %ld -e %ld -g` so you should be able to add parameters to this string

Comment: For other readers: `WinDbg -I` (upper case i) installs itself as post mortem debugger.

Answer (score 2):

I load a bunch of third party extensions and patch system DLLs every time when
testing some hypothesis. To do it repeatedly I create some text file somewhere like `c:\initwind.txt` and put all the in initialization stuff into this text file. Sample file contents below:

```
C:\>type initwind.txt
.echo windbg is starting
.echo loading extra extension sdbgext
.load sdbgext
.echo loading extra extension domdbg
.load domdbg
.echo patching ntdll for leet stuff
u 7c94b8a1 l1
eb 7c94b8a1+3 00
u 7c94b8a1 l1
```

To utilize this text file I have created a bat file in `PATH` whose contents are pasted below.

Notice the usage of `-cfr` for cdb/kd and `-c $$>a<` for windbg to use the same file.

Also, as Ed Chum commented, you can add the following to AeDebug:

```
C:\>reg query "hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\aedebug" /v Debugger

! REG.EXE VERSION 3.0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion\aedebug
    Debugger    REG_SZ  "windbg.exe" -p %ld -e %ld -g -c "$$>a< c:\initwind.txt"
```

contents of bat file

```
C:\>type c:\WINDOWS\rundbg.bat
@ECHO OFF
IF "%1" == "windbg" goto windbg
IF "%1" == "cdb"    goto cdb
IF "%1" == "lkd"    goto lkd
IF "%1" == ""       goto usage

:windbg
IF NOT "%2" == "" goto startwindapp
@call windbg.exe -c "$$>a< c:\initwind.txt"
goto exit
:startwindapp
@call windbg.exe -c "$$>a< c:\initwind.txt" %2
goto EXIT

:cdb
IF NOT "%2" == "" goto startcdbapp
@call cdb.exe -cfr "c:\initwind.txt"
goto exit
:startcdbapp
@call cdb.exe -cfr "c:\initwind.txt" %2
goto EXIT

:lkd
IF NOT "%2" == "" goto startkdapp
@call kd.exe -kl  -cfr "c:\initwind.txt"
goto exit
:startkdapp
@call kd.exe -kl -cfr "c:\initwind.txt" %2
goto EXIT


:usage
echo runwind.bat ^<debugger viz windbg/cdb/kd^> ^<executable / other commands^>
goto exit

:exit
C:\>
```

I can now start windbg / cdb / kd -kl etc just from any command prompt
or  even from Start -> Run  and I can restart the target n number of times without having to worry about doing the init stuff again and again.

Sample output as follows showing `calc.exe` under `cdb.exe` and restarting `calc` again using `.restart` command.

To change init commands all you need is to edit the `c:\initwind.txt`.

```
C:\>rundbg cdb calc
CommandLine: calc

ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
7c90120e cc              int     3
0:000> .echo windbg is starting
windbg is starting
0:000> .echo loading extra extension sdbgext
loading extra extension sdbgext
0:000> .load sdbgext
0:000> .echo loading extra extension domdbg
loading extra extension domdbg
0:000> .load domdbg
dom WinDBG extension v0.3 loaded
0:000> .echo patching ntdll for leet stuff
patching ntdll for leet stuff
0:000> u 7c94b8a1 l1
ntdll!RtlAllocateHeapSlowly+0xde6:
7c94b8a1 81e3ff0fffff    and     ebx,0FFFF0FFFh
0:000> eb 7c94b8a1+3 00
0:000> u 7c94b8a1 l1
ntdll!RtlAllocateHeapSlowly+0xde6:
7c94b8a1 81e3ff00ffff    and     ebx,0FFFF00FFh
0:000> .echo checking the extension chain
checking the extension chain
0:000> .extcmds
.load ntsdexts
.load uext
.load exts
.load ext
.load dbghelp
.load sdbgext
.load domdbg


0:000> .restart
CommandLine: calc

ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
7c90120e cc              int     3
0:000> .echo windbg is starting
windbg is starting
0:000> .echo loading extra extension sdbgext
loading extra extension sdbgext
0:000> .load sdbgext
0:000> .echo loading extra extension domdbg
loading extra extension domdbg
0:000> .load domdbg
dom WinDBG extension v0.3 loaded
0:000> .echo patching ntdll for leet stuff
patching ntdll for leet stuff
0:000> u 7c94b8a1 l1
ntdll!RtlAllocateHeapSlowly+0xde6:
7c94b8a1 81e3ff0fffff    and     ebx,0FFFF0FFFh
0:000> eb 7c94b8a1+3 00
0:000> u 7c94b8a1 l1
ntdll!RtlAllocateHeapSlowly+0xde6:
7c94b8a1 81e3ff00ffff    and     ebx,0FFFF00FFh
0:000> .echo checking the extension chain
checking the extension chain
0:000> .extcmds
.load ntsdexts
.load uext
.load exts
.load ext
.load dbghelp
.load sdbgext
.load domdbg
0:000>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the new WinDbg Preview, you can set up commands that run whenever a new WinDbg session starts.

Open the "Settings" dialog, then go to "Debugging settings", and then scan down the page for "Startup".  Add your commands there.

[image]